# use google maps to map as a base map in arcgis 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am using arcmap 10.1 and am editing my street layer, openstreemap base map I have, but the problem is that this does not have updated new streets and roads, I see that google maps map if you have updated streets and roads, my questions could be used as background maps google maps in arcgis 10.1 to edit my street layer

Comment: You could use QGIS to edit your streets layer instead. It's free, and with the OpenLayers plugin, you can use Google, Bing, Yahoo, or OSM data as your backdrop.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most expedient solution would be to purchase a copy of [Arc2Earth](http://www.arc2earth.com/software/arc2earth/), it will display Google tiles in ArcMap.